# how to validate email in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to validate a email using clojure. How can I do it.

```
(defn validate-email [email]

    )
```

I want to know how will be the function body writeen using regular expressions.

Comment: Have a look at [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: i am new to clojure. I am not able to write correct syntax for email verification

Comment: The downvotes are outright silly. This is a beginner question and it has a larger number of views that other recent #clojure questions.

Comment: Though I didn't downvote this, but it would be a lot better if you state what you have tried/learned and why they don't work.

Comment: Manish, to add to what Davyzhu wrote, you seem to be asking us to write your code from you from the very beginning of your task.  First you have to try to write it yourself.  You can ask for help on the next step, you can ask for help when you get stuck, you can even ask for help on how to think about what to do next.  You have to do some work first.  If you are learning Clojure, you have to do some work to learn some Clojure first, and show us what you tried to do, and tell us what didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn validate-email
  [email]
  (let [pattern #"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"]
    (and (string? email) (re-matches pattern email))))
```

As far as regular expressions in Clojure, this might help: http://www.lispcast.com/clojure-regex

---

Or, [funcool/struct](https://funcool.github.io/struct/latest/) can be used to validate email, beside [other things](https://funcool.github.io/struct/latest/#builtin-validators).

Comment: `re-matches` always looks for complete matches, so there is no need to add either `^` or `$` with it.

Comment: Thanks, the line was certainly pretty long. :) As far as `and` vs. `when` are concerned I on the side of the fence which prefers to use `when` for a single condition. While less lispish, it's more intuitive for newbies that I work with. A matter of taste certainly. We can also go ahead and add a precondition because it better expresses the intent in this case. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of a simple function that will check input `email` string against simple regexp:

```
(defn validate-email [email]
  (re-matches #".+\@.+\..+" email))
```

It will return input `email` if it matches `.+\@.+\..+` regexp and `nil` otherwise:

```
(validate-email "foo@bar.baz") ;=> "foo@bar.baz"
(validate-email "invalid") ;=> nil
(if (validate-email "foo@bar.baz") :valid :invalid) ;=> :valid
(if (validate-email "invalid") :valid :invalid) ;=> :invalid
```

And if you need a *good* regexp to match emails against, see [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1202461).

Answer (score 1):

Note that using a regular expression to identify 'good' or legitimate email addresses is notoriously difficult to get right. There are a number of edge cases which are easily overlooked. It has gotten a lot easier since some of the more arcane mail routing approaches have dropped out of use, but it can still be tricky.

My advice would be to use something like [bouncer](http://leonardoborges/bouncer) which is a validation library which can be used on both the client and server side i.e. for clojure or clojurescript. It has built-in support for email validation. There are numerous other libs which do a similar thing.

This will get you up and running. You can also look at the source code to learn one way this problem can be solved. Later, once you have more experience, you can try doing something similar (but better :-) yourself

Answer (score 1):

`Clojure` has a very useful validation library, i.e. the `valip` library
 If you watch into the `predicates.clj` file, you can see that there are the `email-address?` and `valid-email-domain?` functions and those are exactly for your porpuse.
So you can use it as follows

`(defn validate-email [email]
       (valid-email-domain? email))`

You can use `valid-email-domain` for both clojure, and `email-address` for both `clojure` and `clojurescript`. 
Here it's the link: 
https://github.com/weavejester/valip/blob/master/src/valip/predicates.clj 
with other useful validation functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of discussions on SO and elsewhere of how to match email addresses with regular expressions. It seems to me that what you're asking is how to use regular expressions in Clojure.

The reader recognizes `#"` as starting a literal regular expression, ending in `"`. Example: `#"(t)+"`.

You can also use [`re-pattern`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-pattern) to compile a regular expression from a string, so you could dynamically create a regular expression pattern like so: `(re-pattern (str "^" my-var "$"))`.

---

If you are trying to use a regular expression to match a string in its entirety, you can use [`re-matches`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-matches). It returns `nil` (no match), the original string (it matches), or a vector of `[full-string, capture-1, capture-2, ...]`

```
(re-matches #"abc" "abcdefg") ;; => nil
(re-matches #"abc.*" "abcdefg") ;; => "abcdefg"
(re-matches #"abc(.)(.*)" "abcdefg") ;; => ["abcdefg", "d", "efg"]
```

---

[`re-matcher`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-matcher) takes a regular expression and a string and returns a [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). You can use the [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method to get the next match, or you can use Clojure's [`re-find`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find).

```
(def my-matcher (re-matcher #"[aeiou].[aeiou]" "alienate"))
(re-find my-matcher) ;; => "ali"
(re-find my-matcher) ;; => "ena"
(re-find my-matcher) ;; => nil
```

If you are using a Matcher, then you can use [`re-groups`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-groups) to get the groups from the most recent match.

---

Another use of `re-find` is with a regular expression and a string to return only the first match:

```
(re-find #"[aeiou].[aeiou]" "alienate") ;; => "ali"
```

---

For many cases, you will find [`re-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-seq) to be a more convenient alternative to `re-find` with `re-matcher`. It returns a **lazy** sequence of all matches:

```
(re-seq #"[aeiou].[aeiou]" "alienate") ;; => ("ali", "ena"), lazily
```

---

Finally, you can search and replace with [`replace`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace) and [`replace-first`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace-first). [`re-quote-replacement`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/re-quote-replacement) helps with the annoying matter of escaping characters correctly.